# .net core Identity, getting meaningful login failed reason

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

When a login fails, I wish to know if it was the username, the password or something else.

```
var signinResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
    loginViewModel.UserName,
    loginViewModel.Password,
    false, false);
```

returns SignInResult which just tells me that it's NotAllowed.

Can I get a more meaningful reason from Identity somehow?

Comment: BTW: never be too specific if either username or password failed, this is a security breach. Always keep it "in the middle" like: "Username or password is invalid."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`NotAllowed` means either the Email or Phone Number have't been confirmed (and confirmation is required). You can check this explicitly with something like the following (assuming you have a `UserManager` instance from DI):

```
await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);
await _userManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user);
```

To use either of those two functions, you'll need the `user`:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginViewModel.UserName);
```

To determine whether it was the username or the password that failed, you'll need to first check `IsLockedOut`, `IsNotAllowed` and `RequiresTwoFactor`. If all of these return `false`, the username or password is incorrect. In order to determine which of these is the problem, you can check the return value from `await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user)`. Here's a complete example:

```
var signinResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
    loginViewModel.UserName, loginViewModel.Password, false, false);

var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginViewModel.UserName);

if (signinResult.IsNotAllowed)
{
    if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
    {
        // Email isn't confirmed.
    }

    if (!await _userManager.IsPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user))
    {
        // Phone Number isn't confirmed.
    }
}
else if (signinResult.IsLockedOut)
{
    // Account is locked out.
}
else if (signinResult.RequiresTwoFactor)
{
    // 2FA required.
}
else
{
    // Username or password is incorrect.
    if (user == null)
    {
        // Username is incorrect.
    }
    else
    {
        // Password is incorrect.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`PasswordSignInAsync` returns only a generic failure if the username/password is incorrect. This is because you really shouldn't be exposing which is wrong in the first place. If you explicitly tell the end-user that the password is wrong, then they now know that the username is good. If this is a malicious user, you've halved their work. Now they can just brute-force the password.

If you do want this information, though, simply attempt to get the user by the username first:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginViewModel.UserName);
if (user == null)
{
    // username is invalid
}

// Now attempt to login with password.
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for the answer and the security explanation.
I plan to solve this by giving only a generic error message on screen and emailing the full reason to user.  In this case the username is the email.  From a usability point of view I think it’s useful to tell user if they are trying to log in with a non-registered email, as they may have multiple emails and registered under a different one.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was one of the most silly reason, I seeded an Admin user and forgot to mark `EmailConfirmed` to true and had `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)` in my `ConfigureServices` method.
Make sure you have not required Confirmed Account while login or if the user you are trying to login has his email confirmed.